# Using jQuery to find elements inside of a div that was loaded with $.load

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, jquery-load

Here's my code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#test').load('http://foobar.com/view.php?id=1186', function() {        
            console.log($('.weekdates'));

            var weeks = $('.weekdates');
            weeks.each(function(i, val) {
                alert($(this).text());                        
            });                              
        });                
    });
</script>
```

The result of the `console.log` call is:

```
[prevObject: b.fn.b.init[1], context: document, selector: ".weekdates", jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function…]
context: document
length: 0
prevObject: b.fn.b.init[1]
selector: ".weekdates"
__proto__: Object[0]
```

Any ideas why the elements are not being found in the resulting set? Does it have something to do with loading the HTML dynamically?

Here's the HTML that is added:

```
<h3 class="weekdates"> 23 de enero -  29 de enero</h3>
```

Comment: What is the html that is retrieved?

Comment: Let me edit in what HTML is added to `#test`.

Comment: is the html actually being added to the dom?  Basically is the load actually loading?  And what are you going to do with the h3s once added?  it doesn't answer your question but if you're just adding an event ot them you can do it with the .on method.  If you need the text you can rewrite this as an ajax request and send the text as part of a json

Comment: @JohnB: How can I use the `on()` method to parse through results when the document is actually loaded?

Comment: @Serg you would use it in tandem with an event, like click.  $(document.body).on('click', 'h3.weekdates', function() {alert($(this).text();});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly, you can use jquery selectors on HTML returned from an ajax call like so, once you have loaded it into a jQuery object variable...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#test').load('http://foobar.com/view.php?id=1186', function(html) {        
            var $html = $(html);                            
        });                
    });
</script>
```

But honestly, it seems like you're attempting to loop through results. If this is JSON you're returning from the server, you need $.getJSON()

```
$.getJSON('http://foobar.com/view.php?id=1186', function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    // deal with item
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm not getting JSON, I'm fetching a full web page for parsing purposes on the client side. I'll take a look at your first suggestion, thank you!

Comment: Then yes, once you load up the markup, make it into a jquery variable. As an aside, if you need to parse the markup before adding it to the dom, best to use $.get() instead of load...